# How to hide part of status bar, when custom side menu presented

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, statusbar, side-menu

I have a custom `Side Menu` class based on `UIViewController`. Presenting of `Side menu` looks like:

```
extension UIViewController: MenuPresentableProtocol {

    func setupMenu() {
        guard let menu = AppDelegate.shared.menu else { return }
        menu.view.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(menu.view)
        menu.view.frame.origin.x = -UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }

}
```

This means that the `appearance` of the `status bar` depends on the current `ViewControllers` `prefersStatusBarHidden` property, which in this case is `false`.

But I need to hide part of the `status bar` under the `side menu`. Is there a way for implement this?

**This what I have:**

**When menu hidden, it looks good.**

[image]

**But when menu presents, ...**

[image]

P.S. I tried to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683660/how-side-menu-can-cover-part-of-status-bar), but it didn't help me.

Comment: I think it would look better to either 1) draw the menu _below_ the status bar, or 2) hide the status bar when the menu is open. #1 is better, if only because #2 would cause the screen to jump up and down 20 pixels whenever the menu appeared and disappeared.

Comment: @NRitH, #2 - bad implementation, I agree. I don't want to do this. #1 - haven't got a difference with my implementation, but status bar is visible, and it's confused a customer.

Comment: It's not recommended to hide the status bar (or part of it) if you aren't providing the full screen experience (i.e. viewing full screen media like photos/videos) to the user. You might want to have a look at the [Status Bar HIG](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/status-bars/) from Apple.

Comment: I know, but I need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can hide the status bar fully OR you can show full. There is no way to hide part of status bar.

You can use the same background color as statusbar's textcolor in side menu and some opposite color on view controller. In this case, statusbar's text color will have same color as your sidemenu's background color, it means that text will not be visible. So, it will give effect that your half statusbar is hidden and half not.

You will not find any single app on appstore with such case that you want, as it is not possible at all. If some app is looking to have same effect, then check its sidemenu's background color and statusbar's text color. That both will be same.

Answer (score 1):

Answers are right, you cannot hide just a part of the status bar. 
However you can give an almost-perfect illusion you do it by rebuilding your own statusbar clone and display it as you wish: iOS gives you the infos you need:

- the [time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date),
- your [carrier name](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcarrier),
- the [battery level](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620042-batterylevel)
- and battery [charging state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/batterystate)...
- You will just miss the real cellular signal strength info, but you will then need to draw momentarily a fake one just for the time to present you menu and do your animation...

At the end this is more an art work than hard coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was hoping that there is a simple solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will actually hide your status bar with a view

```
        UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 20)] autorelease];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PortraitNavigationBG"]]; 
        //or use same color as your background

        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:view];
```